# windows phone 7 appstore?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile

I am new to windows mobile.is microsoft's  http://marketplace.windowsphone.com/ enough to get applications for windows phone 7 OS?I have heard about windows phone 7 os is differed from windows mobile 6.5 OS.can we download apps for both from same app store?The Application developed for previous versions will run in windows mobile phone 7?

Answer (score 1):

The development and software for WP7 is very separate to WM6.5 and earlier:

- "Back end code" can be considered roughly equivalent - WP7 uses a version of the Compact Framework
- but WP7 is a much more closed/controlled/managed environment.
- and the UI layers for WP7 is very different to WM6 - WP7 is Silverlight and XNA, WM6 is mainly "winforms"

For getting started on WP7 see - http://create.msdn.com

While both WM6 and WP7 app stores are both managed through http://create.msdn.com the marketplaces themselves are very separate entities - apps from 6 cannot be used on 7, and apps on 7 cannot be used on 6...